# WebDriverException: Message: '' ; Stacktrace: Method get threw an error in [No file name]

Tags: selenium, python-2.7, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am running selenium test on Grid with jar 2.28.0 and the Firefox version as 18.0

Intermittently I am getting below error in few of my test cases:

```
self.execute(Command.SWITCH_TO_FRAME, {'id': None}) File "/var/home/automation/quality/framework/1.3/lib/extern/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
line 156, in execute self.error_handler.check_response(response) File "/var/home/automation/quality/framework/1.3/lib/extern/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
line 147, in check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

WebDriverException: Message: '' ; Stacktrace: Method get threw an error in [No file name]
```

The tests are run by setting proxy in the browser, and the failure selenium call differ in each run.